# I have to prove this inequality. I was just looking for a solution to this problem as I have been stuck on it for a very long time.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, radicals

> Show that if $a$ and $h$ are positive numbers with $h<a^2$ then
>   $$\sqrt{a^2+h}-a<\frac{h}{2a}<a-\sqrt{a^2-h}$$

Comment: Please turn to informative titles. Please add to the body of the question your input to the problem.

Comment: Two upvotes for a straight PSQ? Why?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for me is to use the AM-GM inequality: $A + B > 2\sqrt{AB}\,$ for all non-negative $A \not = B$. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

The **inequality on the right** is equivalent to:
$$2a^2-h > 2 a\sqrt{a^2-h}$$ 
which is a direct consequence of the AM-GM inequality:
$$
2a^2-h = a^2 + (a^2-h) > 2\sqrt{a^2 (a^2-h)} = 2a\sqrt{a^2-h}.
$$

Similarly, the **inequality on the left** is equivalent to:
$$2a^2+h > 2 a\sqrt{a^2+h}$$ 
which is again a direct consequence of the AM-GM inequality:
$$
2a^2+h = a^2 + (a^2+h) > 2\sqrt{a^2 (a^2+h)} = 2a\sqrt{a^2+h}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove that
$$\sqrt{a^2-h}<\frac{2a^2-h}{2a}$$ and
$$\sqrt{a^2+h}<\frac{h+2a^2}{2a}.$$
Both inequalities are obviously true after squaring of the both sides.

In the both cases we'll get $h^2>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a calculus-based solution . . .

For $x > 0$, let $f(x) =\sqrt{x}$.

Then $f$ is differentiable and $f'(x) = {\large{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}}}$.

Note that $f'$ is decreasing.

Suppose $0 < h < a^2$.

\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;f(a^2) &= \sqrt{a^2} = a
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;
\\[4pt]
f'(a^2) &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a^2}}=\frac{1}{2a}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
By the Mean Value Theorem, there exists $c \in (a^2,a^2+h)$ such that
\begin{align*}
&\frac{f(a^2 + h) - f(a^2)}{h} = f'(c)\\[6pt]
\implies\;&\frac{f(a^2 + h) - f(a^2)}{h} < f'(a^2)&&\text{[since $f'$ is decreasing]}\\[6pt]
\implies\;&\frac{\sqrt{a^2+h}-a}{h} < \frac{1}{2a}\\[6pt]
\implies\;&\sqrt{a^2+h}-a <  \frac{h}{2a}\\[6pt]
\end{align*}
Similarly, by the Mean Value Theorem, there exists $c \in (a^2-h,a^2)$ such that
\begin{align*}
&\frac{f(a^2-h) - f(a^2)}{-h} = f'(c)\\[6pt]
\implies\;&\frac{f(a^2) - f(a^2-h)}{h} = f'(c)\\[6pt]
\implies\;&\frac{f(a^2) - f(a^2-h)}{h} > f'(a^2)&&\text{[since $f'$ is decreasing]}\\[6pt]
\implies\;&\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-h}}{h} > \frac{1}{2a}\\[6pt]
\implies\;&a-\sqrt{a^2-h} >  \frac{h}{2a}\\[6pt]
\end{align*}
which completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest approach would be to notice that
$$
\sqrt{a^2+h}-a=\frac{h}{\sqrt{a^2+h}+a},\qquad a-\sqrt{a^2-h}=\frac{h}{a+\sqrt{a^2-h}}.
$$
After that you only need to prove
$$
a+\sqrt{a^2-h}<2a<a+\sqrt{a^2+h}
$$
which is as obvious as it can get.